# Negative searches

Tags: feature-request, search

I think a useful feature would be negative searches: searches in which at least one term is constrained to not occur (but no more than all but one terms, of course -- you wouldn't want to bring back all/almost all questions).

This would be useful both for bare terms

```
prime -ideal
```

and tags

```
diophantine -[elementary-number-theory]
```

Comment: Have you tried it? For me, searching "prime -ideal" works as expected!

Comment: FWIW, Google also recognizes search operators like `-`. So something like `site:math.stackexchange.com +prime -ideal` works nicely if the built-in search is not to your taste.

Answer (score 5):

I'm tempted to close this as "not a real question", because as Hendrik said in a comment:

- [Now you see it](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=searches),
- [Now you don't](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=searches++-negative&submit=search),
- [Nor do you now](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=searches++-[feature-request]&submit=search).

So it appears that both of the requested features are already features....

Comment: I think it was very cute to perform the searches on this question. I liked that a lot.

Comment: That's fascinating, because it did not work at all in my tests (on math.se).  I'll have to experiment and get back to you.